# Trace of matrix power

Tags: diagonalization, trace

If $A$ is diagonalizable and $trace(A^2) = 0$ , prove what the properties of $A$ are.

Does this relate to $A$ being nilpotent?
And what is the general equation for a diagonalizable power matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable there are unitary matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=UDU^{-1}$ thus $A^2=UDU^{-1}UDU^{-1}=UD^2 U^{-1}$ thus $trace(A^2)=trace(UD^2 U^{-1}) =trace(D^2)=0$ this means $D=0$ thus $A=U0U^{-1}=0$

for diagonal matrix
$$D=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} &  0  & \ldots & 0\\
0  &  a_{22} & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
we have 
$$D^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}^2 &  0  & \ldots & 0\\
0  &  a_{22}^2 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
  thus if $trace D^2=0$ implies $D=0$

Comment: $A=diag(1,i)$? $\mbox{} $

Comment: dear the symbole you have used is unfamiliar to me.